# Eliminar elementos duplicados de un array de objetos en javascript

Tags: javascript

Como puedo eliminiar elementos duplicados de un array cuando hago el push.Tengo un array llamado carrito que al presionar el boton de agregar (btnAgregar) me hace un push de lo que he presionado(por eso los dataset). El problema es que si presiono dos veces un mismo producto me lo agrega varias veces al array carrito. Como debería hacer para que no hayan elementos duplicados en el array carrito.

```
let carrito=[]

btnAgregar.onclick=AgregarCarrito;

function AgregarCarrito(){
     //precios
  
    //array carrito
        carrito.push({
            imagen: this.dataset.src,
            nombre: this.dataset.nombre,
            categoria: this.dataset.categoria,
            precio: this.dataset.precio,
            cantidad: parseInt(this.dataset.cantidad),
        });  
  
  
  
    }
```

Comment: Deberías realizar una búsqueda dentro de tu variable _carrito_, utilizando un [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), etc y en caso que obtengas datos distintos de `undefined` o _0_, - dependiendo el método que uses -, no lo agregas ya que existen

Comment: Como identificas cada producto ?? Lo que te recomiendo es que en tu evento de agregar, primero recorras tu arreglo, si ya existe un producto, solo actualiza la cantidad, pero para hacer eso necesitas identificar cada producto con **ID**.

Comment: @Michel, tienes acceso a alguna propiedad `id` para cada producto?

Answer (score 1):

1.- Primero identifica cada producto con un **ID**

2.- Antes de agregar un nuevo producto, recorre tu **arreglo de objetos** y valida si el ID del nuevo producto es igual solo actualiza su **cantidad**, y ya no realizas el **push**

3.- Te muestro un ejemplo para que puedas entenderlo mejor y aplicarlo a tu proyecto:

1.- Tengo un **Boton** que simulará agregar un nuevo producto a mi carrito:

```
let btnAdd = document.querySelector('#add-to-cart');
```

2.- Tengo un producto de prueba en mi arreglo de **carrito:**

```
let carrito = [{
            idProduct: 21,
            imagen: 'Soy una imagen',
            nombre: 'Teclado Gamer',
            categoria: 'Tecnologia',
            precio: '1000MXN',
            cantidad: 4,
        }];
```

3.- Tengo un **nuevo producto** de prueba que voy a agregar, nota que ambos tienen el mismo **ID:**

```
nuevoProductoAgregado = {
  idProduct: 21,
            imagen: 'Soy una imagen',
            nombre: 'Teclado Gamer',
            categoria: 'Tecnologia',
            precio: '1000MXN',
            cantidad: 4,
}
```

4.- Le agrego un evento de tipo click a mi boton, este agregará el nuevo producto de prueba

```
btnAdd.addEventListener('click', function(){
 
})
```

5.- Dentro de este evento tengo que recorrer mi **carrito** y verificar si ya existe ese producto, de ser asi, solo actualizo su cantidad:

```
carrito.forEach((producto) =>{
    if(producto.idProduct === nuevoProductoAgregado.idProduct){
      producto.cantidad++;
    }else{
      //REALIZAS EL PUSH
     }
    console.log(carrito);
  })
```

Te muestro el ejemplo corriendo, para que puedas testearlo:

```js
let btnAdd = document.querySelector('#add-to-cart');

let carrito = [{
            idProduct: 21,
            imagen: 'Soy una imagen',
            nombre: 'Teclado Gamer',
            categoria: 'Tecnologia',
            precio: '1000MXN',
            cantidad: 4,
        }];


nuevoProductoAgregado = {
  idProduct: 21,
            imagen: 'Soy una imagen',
            nombre: 'Teclado Gamer',
            categoria: 'Tecnologia',
            precio: '1000MXN',
            cantidad: 4,
}

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', function(){
  carrito.forEach((producto) =>{
    if(producto.idProduct === nuevoProductoAgregado.idProduct){
      producto.cantidad++;
    }
    console.log(carrito);
  })
})
```

```html
<button id="add-to-cart">AGREGAR AL CARRITO</button>
```

NOTA: En el ejemplo solo estoy sumando de **uno en uno** En realidad lo que tienes que hacer es sumarle la cantidad del producto en tu carrito, mas la cantidad del producto nuevo. Pero bueno eso lo puedes realizar tu, no tiene mucho misterio.

Comment: Cómo le pasas el ítem desde el _front_ hacia el controller?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Eso sería otra pregunta, si deseas saber como realizar eso, postula tu pregunta y con gusto te respondo, aunque el **item** se lo deberías de pasar cuando se realiza el **checkout** o almenos que quieras validar algo de importancia en ese item, si es necesario pasarlo al **backend** Puedes realizarlo de manera asincrona con la api de **fetch** que es propia de JavaScript. Saludos desde México.

Comment: No, la pregunta del OP fue: _de que forma puede implementar una actualización o modificación de un item, utilizando sólo una función_; entonces, de alguna forma tienes que enviar el item que deseas crear/actualizar desde tu formulario hacia tu controller - dejo fuera la API que se encarga de dicha operacion -, es un punto que deberías tener en cuenta para que el OP tenga un mejor contexto. Y lo otro, no hay necesidad de asignarle mediante JQuery el evento click al botón, para eso `AngularJS` tiene la propiedad [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Creo que andas un poco perdido, en el ejemplo que di solo estoy utilizando **Vanilla JavaScript**, No hay Jquery, lee detenidamente mi codigo, tu ya estas hablando de cosas mayores, quieres meter a **AngularJs** cuando el código del usuario es netamente puro de JavaScript, si en las etiquetas de la pregunta estuviera **Angular,** no hubiera respondido, ya que no se nada de Angular, solo trabajo con **ReactJS** Saludos cordiales desde México.